# How to pass $BUILD_NUMBER in jenkins on remote host

Tags: hudson, jenkins

I am trying to execute shell script on remote host but I am not sure how to pass Jenkins Environment Variable for Ex: BUILD_NUMBER

Execute shell script on remote host using ssh
    SSH site

Could some one let me know how to do it?
Thanks
praveen

Answer (score 1):

Just pass $BUILD_NUMBER as a parameter to your remote shell script when you fill out the Command field in your build step.  For example:

Remote shell script contents:

```
echo "Build number is $1"
```

Command field contents:

```
"/path/to/myshellscript $BUILD_NUMBER"
```

Comment: I tried this already did not work, more information below ./deploy.sh  --buildnumber  $BUILD_NUMBER is not working, but if I pass ./deploy.sh --buildnumber  10 it works and executes in the remote hosts, basically $BUILD_NUMBER is not working in the remote shell but it works in the same shell.Any idea?

Comment: Sorry about that - the SSH build step seems to be treating quotes in a strange way.  Surrounding the command to be executed with double quotes should work (this evaluates any environment variables locally before the command is executed on the remote host), but Jenkins seems to be swallowing the quotes somehow and I can't figure out how to get it to work.  I'll keep looking.

Comment: No problem, only way is as a turn arround shh to the box in the current shell and run the command with the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case somebody is still puzzling over this issue, as the SSH Exec command still behaves in the same undocumented way, you need to quote the parameters you wish to pass to the command, for example :

`/path/to/script "$BUILD_NUMBER" "$GIT_BRANCH"`

Answer (score 0):

Using SSH plugin to execute ssh on remote host, do below :

```
export BUILD_NUMBER
/path/to/myshellscript
```